# How to extract phrase from string using Range?

Tags: ios, swift

This sounds easy, but I am stumped. The syntax and functions of Range are very confusing to me.

I have a URL like this:

```
https://github.com/shakked/Command-for-Instagram/blob/master/Analytics%20Pro.md#global-best-time-to-post
```

I need to extract the part `#global-best-time-to-post`, essentially the `#` to the end of the string.

`urlString.rangeOfString("#")` returns `Range`
Then I tried doing this assuming that calling `advanceBy(100)` would just go to the end of the string but instead it crashes.

```
hashtag = urlString.substringWithRange(range.startIndex...range.endIndex.advancedBy(100))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest and best way to do this is use `NSURL`, I included how to do it with `split` and `rangeOfString`:

```
import Foundation

let urlString = "https://github.com/shakked/Command-for-Instagram/blob/master/Analytics%20Pro.md#global-best-time-to-post"

// using NSURL - best option since it validates the URL
if let url = NSURL(string: urlString),
  fragment = url.fragment {
  print(fragment)
}
// output: "global-best-time-to-post"

// using split - pure Swift, no Foundation necessary
let split = urlString.characters.split("#")
if split.count > 1,
  let fragment = split.last {
  print(String(fragment))
}
// output: "global-best-time-to-post"

// using rangeofString - asked in the question
if let endOctothorpe = urlString.rangeOfString("#")?.endIndex {
  // Note that I use the index of the end of the found Range 
  // and the index of the end of the urlString to form the 
  // Range of my string
  let fragment = urlString[endOctothorpe..<urlString.endIndex]
  print(fragment)
}
// output: "global-best-time-to-post"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `substringFromIndex`

```
let string = "https://github.com..."
if let range = string.rangeOfString("#") {
  let substring = string.substringFromIndex(range.endIndex)
}
```

but I'd prefer the `NSURL` way.

Answer (score -1):

use componentsSeparatedByString method

```
let url = "https://github.com/shakked/Command-for-Instagram/blob/master/Analytics%20Pro.md#global-best-time-to-post"
let splitArray = url.componentsSeparatedByString("#")
```

your required last text phrase (without # char) will be at the last index of the `splitArray` , you can concatenate the # with your phrase

```
var myPhrase = "#\(splitArray[splitArray.count-1])"
print(myPhrase)
```

Comment: I misunderstood the question :(